# Rails - append attributes and add to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having a slight problem with appending data and then adding it into the array.

Here is my code

```
@order.orderdesc ||= []

@cart.line_items.each do |item|
 @order.orderdesc += item.quantity +  "x" + item.product.title
end
```

I only want to add  item.quantity and item.product.title. They can be accessed.

Thanks

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you want to add "stuff" in an array, the `+=` is not made for that. You can use the `<<`  operator (append at the end of the array):

```
@order.orderdesc ||= []

@cart.line_items.each do |item|
 @order.orderdesc << item.quantity +  "x" + item.product.title
end
```

Or you can use `.push()`:

```
@order.orderdesc ||= []

@cart.line_items.each do |item|
 @order.orderdesc.push( item.quantity +  "x" + item.product.title )
end
```

- Documentation: http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/push